# React-tree-js MeshTransmissionMaterial randomly change opacity after motion

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

[image: error]
[image: normal]

Hello! I am new to tree.js and am a bit lost with this bug.
After what seems to be random time interval,
The object that uses the MeshTransmissionMaterial material, changes behaviour.

Do you know where I could investigate ?

I dont expect the behaviour of the material to change with time

Answer (score 0):

Found the pb,

It ended up beeing a problem just on MacOs M1.
If you clamp the transimission.rgb color on positive values, the error dont propagate and you do not see the dark noise.